# Problema com Expressão Regular

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
preg_match('<[ \w"=]+name="xhpc_composerid"[ \w="]+>',$exec,$result1);
echo $result1[0];
//input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="xhpc_composerid" value="u_0_1k" 

preg_match('/value="[\w]+"/i',$result1[0],$result2);
echo $result2[0];
// value="u_0_1k"

$result3 = preg_replace('/value="/i',"ab123",$result2[0]);
echo $result3[0];
// a

$result4 = substr($result3[0],0,-1);
echo $result4;
// (vazio)
```

A questão é, `$result2` imprimi `value="u_0_1k"`, porquê `$result3` imprimi `a`? Minha regex deve estar correta, eu esperava algo como: `u_0_1k"`, ai na `$result4` iria imprimir o que imprimiu na `$result3` só que sem aspas duplas, o que posso estar errando?

Comment: Agora que reparei, imprime *A* provavelmente por isso `$result3[0]`, remova o `[0]` pois dessa forma você está pegando a primeira letra apenas. `echo $result3` // **ab123u_0_1k"**

Comment: Perfeito! Eu pensava que retornava um array, mas pelo que li, só retorna array se o subject do preg_replace for um array, ou seja, se o texto a sofrer o replacement for um array também, ai ele retornaria um array, então acabei usando `$result3[0]` na intenção de estar mexendo com array, agradeço pela atenção!

Comment: Use uma ER para acessar direto o `value`. Não seria melhor, ou você modifica o valor durante o processo?

Comment: uma ER para acessar direto o `value`? eu não consegui imaginar como fazer isso.. para meu caso acredito que não de, já que o `value` pode estar no inicio, no meio dos atributos do input, então não cogitei a possibilidade de ter 1 ER só..

Comment: Eu não domino ER, mas se você modificar sua pergunta acredito que alguém com mais conhecimento possa responder apropriadamente com uma ER para você resolver seu caso.

Comment: Ok @PapaCharlie, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Ok, depois com mais tempo eu crio uma resposta com mais explicação.

Comment: Não cheguei a entender o que pretendes ao certo.

Answer (score 1):

Nao entendi completamente o que era perguntado.
Abaixo exemplifica-se:

- extração de algumas partes (atributos xml)
- substituição de um valor (value) por um novo valor.

tomando como base o teu exemplo

```
<?php

$exemplo='<xxx "type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="xhpc_composerid" value="u_0_1k">';

preg_match('<.*? name="(.*?)".*? value="(.*?)".*?>',$exemplo,$result);
echo "id    encontrado foi...  $result[1]\n";
echo "valor encontrado foi...  $result[2]\n";

$r = preg_replace('/(value=")(.*?)"/',"$1Novo valor", $exemplo);
echo "$r\n";

?>
```

ao executar (`php file`) produz:

```
id    encontrado foi...  xhpc_composerid
valor encontrado foi...  u_0_1k
<xxx "type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="xhpc_composerid" value="Novo valor>
```